# C# Basic stack arithmetic operations

Tags: c#, math, stack

I have two classes one Calculator and another Test class. Test class contains multiple expected output test and calculator contains method to perform arithmetic operation my question is: Why does TestOne output 105 instead of 9 and TestTwo output 6 instead of 2.

Here are the tests.

```
public void TestOne()
{
    var c= new Calc();
    c.Add(5);
    c.Add(7);
    c.Undo();
    c.Subtract(2);
    c.Multiply(7);
    c.Undo();
    c.Multiply(3);
}

public void TestTwo()
{
    var c= new Calc();
    c.Add(2);
    c.Add(3);
    c.Add(4);
    ex.Undo();
    c.RepeatLastCommand();
}
```

Here are the functionalities of the application

```
public class Calc
{
    int total= 0;
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();

    public int Value
    {
        get { return total; }
        set { total= value; }
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    { 
        total = total + value;
        stack.Push(value); 
    }

    public void Subtract(int value)
    {
        total = total - value;
        stack.Push(total);
    }

    public void Multiply(int value)
    {
        total= total * value;
        stack.Push(total);
    }

    public void RepeatLastCommand()
    {
        int topOfStack =stack.Peek();
        total += topOfStack;
     }

     public void Undo()
     {
         total = stack.Pop();
         if (stack.Count > 0)
         {
             int safe = stack.Pop();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger (which we aren't going to do for you), where specifically does the logic deviate from what you expect?

Comment: The only issue I can think of are the logic I am applying to complete the operation. I am generally new to this field so I was hoping someone could spot a mistake after trying to figure out for several hours.

Comment: I'm not really sure what that `Undo` method is doing, really.  Both `Undo` and `RepeatLastCommand` don't seem to support any operations other than addition, and I don't think `Undo` is even supporting that correctly.  Your best bet is to simply step through this in a debugger and keep track of the running values after each line of code.  That should tell you where a value changes in an unexpected way.

Comment: @David I am a clone src on Git but I am try I am still generally new to this. Repeat is for example on TestTwo. If Repeat is executed it should execute undo() but I still haven't got my head round to calling it.

Comment: He should use the command pattern but it might be a little too advanced.

Answer (score 4):

At first glance you need to change your Undo method to

```
public void Undo()
{
    if(stack.Count > 0 ) stack.Pop();
    total = stack.Peek();
}
```

also the Add method should Push on the stack the Total variable not the value passed

```
public void Add(int value)
{
    total = total + value;
    stack.Push(total);
}
```

However resolving the RepeatLastCommand operation is a bit more complext and cannot be achieved with this structure, you need to store in your stack variable also the operation executed and the value used in that operation.

I think that the solution presented in another answer by `csdp000` could drive you on the right track.

Regarding instead your request to clarify the change in the Undo, it is simple. The Pop operation extracts from the top of the stack the value that you have last Push(ed), this value is the current **total**, you are interested to restore the previous value so discard the actual top and assign to total the new top of the stack

**EDIT**
After some thinking about the RepeatLastAction I have rewritten your class to store, instead of an integer an instance of a class that contains all the information about the operation executed by your Calc class

```
public class Calc
{
    bool undoAction = false;
    int total = 0;
    Stack<CalcAction> stack = new Stack<CalcAction>();

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return total;
        }
        set
        {
            total = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        CalcAction act = new CalcAction() 
        { 
            operation = Add, 
            actionTotal = total + value, 
            actionValue = value 
        };
        total = act.actionTotal;
        stack.Push(act);
        undoAction = false;
    }

    public void Subtract(int value)
    {
        CalcAction act = new CalcAction()
        {
            operation = Subtract,
            actionTotal = total - value,
            actionValue = value
        };
        total = act.actionTotal;
        stack.Push(act);
        undoAction = false;
    }

    public void Multiply(int value)
    {
        CalcAction act = new CalcAction()
        {
            operation = Multiply,
            actionTotal = total * value,
            actionValue = value
        };
        total = act.actionTotal;
        stack.Push(act);
        undoAction = false;
    }

    public void RepeatLastCommand()
    {
        if (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            if(undoAction)
                Undo();
            else
            {
                CalcAction act = stack.Peek();
                act.operation(act.actionValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        if (stack.Count > 0) stack.Pop();
        total = ((CalcAction)stack.Peek()).actionTotal;
        undoAction = true;
    }

    internal class CalcAction
    {
        public Action<int> operation;
        public int actionValue;
        public int actionTotal;
    }
}
```

Here the main change is the internal class CalcAction that is stored in the stack with the info on the current operation. This allows the RepeatLastAction method to know which operation to re-execute. The only exception is the Undo operation that is kept out from the stack because its signature is different from the Add/Subtract/Multiply

Comment: Hello fellow Steve. From that small change it seem to have fixed TestOne but TestOne still an issue. However System.InvalidOpertation: Stack empty has triggered Thank you, can you explain the difference.

Comment: What you expect to happen with RepeatLastCommand? This seems not resolvable with this structure, you need to store also the operators and in case of Undo also that

Comment: I mean, if you call RepeatLastCommand after an Undo you want to execute an Undo, instead if you have RepeatLastCommand after an Add/Subtract/Divide/Multiply you want to execute that command again, but at that point you need to have stored also the last action and the parameter passed to that action. Just a single Stack<int> is not enough.

Comment: you can store actions? I will look at this. TestOne is throwing 10 do you know why?

Comment: Agreed on RepeatLastCommand.  I did step through it, and when it hits that in the second test, instead of undoing the Add(3) or undoing the Undo, it actually undoes an Add(5) which is the aggregate of the Add(2) and Add(3).  I'm afraid it would take a decent amount of coding to get it to work right.

Comment: @StevenJones did you make all the changes Steve put forth?  I did and I am getting 9 from Test1 now.

Comment: @WDS Yes I did 10 atm, I will look at it more. I guess my repeat still needs a lot of work

Comment: @StevenJones what do you expect to happen when RepeatLastCommand follows an Undo action?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

Add operationInfo,

```
public class CalcFix
{
    struct OperStruct
    {
        public Action<int> OperFunc;
        public int OperValue;
        public static OperStruct OperSet(Action<int> _operFunc, int _operValue)
        {
            OperStruct operStru = new OperStruct();

            operStru.OperFunc = _operFunc;
            operStru.OperValue = _operValue;
            return operStru;
        }

    }

    private bool _undo = false;
    private int _total = 0;
    private Dictionary<Action<int>, Action<int>> _reverseOper = new Dictionary<Action<int>, Action<int>>();
    private Stack<OperStruct> stack = new Stack<OperStruct>();

    public CalcFix()
    {
        _reverseOper.Add(Add, Subtract);
        _reverseOper.Add(Subtract, Add);
        _reverseOper.Add(Multiply, Division);
        _reverseOper.Add(Division, Multiply);
    }


    public int Value { get { return _total; } }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        _total += value;
        _undo = false;
        stack.Push(OperStruct.OperSet(Add, value));
    }
    public void Subtract(int value)
    {
        _total -= value;
        _undo = false;
        stack.Push(OperStruct.OperSet(Subtract, value));
    }
    public void Multiply(int value)
    {
        _total *= value;
        _undo = false;
        stack.Push(OperStruct.OperSet(Multiply, value));
    }
    public void Division(int value)
    {
        _total /= value;
        _undo = false;
        stack.Push(OperStruct.OperSet(Division, value));
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        OperStruct operFunc = stack.Pop();
        if (operFunc.OperFunc != null && _reverseOper.ContainsKey(operFunc.OperFunc))
        { 
            _reverseOper[operFunc.OperFunc](operFunc.OperValue);
            _undo = true;
        }
    }

    public void RepeatLastCommand()
    {
        OperStruct topOfStack = stack.Peek();
        if (stack.Count > 1)
        {
            if (topOfStack.OperFunc != null)
            {
                if (!_undo) // if not called undo
                    _reverseOper[topOfStack.OperFunc](topOfStack.OperValue);
                else // called undo
                {
                    stack.Pop();
                    topOfStack = stack.Pop();
                    _reverseOper[topOfStack.OperFunc](topOfStack.OperValue);
                    _undo = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void TestTwo()
{
    var c = new CalcFix();
    c.Add(2);
    c.Add(3);
    c.Add(4);
    System.Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
    c.Undo();
    System.Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
    c.RepeatLastCommand();
    System.Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
    c.RepeatLastCommand();
    System.Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    TestTwo();
}
```

change code

output:
9
5
2
0

Comment: This seems to be pretty the same thing that I was trying to write to solve the problem of the RepeatLastCommand. Good work

Comment: The only problem seems to be if the RepeatLastCommand follows an Add/Subtract or Multiply. It reverts as an Undo instead of repeating the Add/Subtract/Multiply

Comment: @Steve Thank you, your code very clean. do you have any suggestions how to resolve the problem?

Comment: In my code I keep the Undo action outside the stack and set a flag to handle this special situation. Probably it is applicable to your code but certainly a more elegant solution would be better

Comment: Good try, but doesn't work in general. Multiplication by zero and integer division like 7/3 cannot be undone this way.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of bugs in this class.

(1) `Add` is pushing **value** while other operations are pushing **total**
(2) If you need undo, all the operations should push **total** before modifying it.
(3) Undo should simply do a pop.
(4) `RepeatLastCommand` is meaningless because you store only the result in the stack, not the operation.

**EDIT**
In the previous part I was trying to answer your original question - **why** you are getting such a results. But if the question is how to make it work, here is IMO the simplest way. As mentioned above, in order to support `Undo`, all we need is to store the **previous** value in the stack. And in order to support the `RepeatLastCommand`, all we need is to store the **last command** :-)

Here is one of the possible implementations:

```
public class Calc
{
    int total = 0;
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
    Action lastCommand;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return total; }
        set { Execute(() => total = value); }
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        Execute(() => total += value);
    }

    public void Subtract(int value)
    {
        Execute(() => total -= value);
    }

    public void Multiply(int value)
    {
        Execute(() => total *= value);
    }

    public void Divide(int value)
    {
        Execute(() => total /= value);
    }

    public void Negate()
    {
        Execute(() => total = -total);
    }

    public void RepeatLastCommand()
    {
        if (lastCommand != null)
            lastCommand();
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        Execute(() => { if (stack.Count > 0) total = stack.Pop(); }, undoable: false);
    }

    private void Execute(Action command, bool undoable = true)
    {
        var oldValue = total;
        command();
        lastCommand = command;
        if (undoable) stack.Push(oldValue);
    }
}
```

Note that we don't need a special flags or classes like in some other answers because the C# `closure` will do all that for us, and also allows us to abstract the operation and support both binary, unary or no arg operations. For demonstration purposes, I've added `Negate` and `Divide` actions, as well as making `Value` set operation undoable (you can remove that if you don't need it).